# XSLT_1: Add missing node based on child element value

Tags: xslt-1.0

could you please assist with solution below.

The sources files some times missing hole segment (**which has child 'count' element with number 3**). In this case I need to map all missing node segment and add some specific values.

Please see correct source xml file below which has all 'node' segments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <group>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>2</count>
      <value>value_2</value>
    </node>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>3</count>
      <value>value_3</value>
    </node>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>1</count>
      <value>value_1</value>
    </node>
  </group>
</root>
```

The below one doesn't have all segments in place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <group>
        <node segment="1">
          <count>2</count>
          <value>value_2</value>
        </node>
        <node segment="1">
          <count>1</count>
          <value>value_1</value>
        </node>
      </group>
    </root>
```

Mising part is:

```
<node segment="1">
   <count>3</count>
   <value>value_3</value>
</node>
```

I have worked on xslt script below which doesn't give me the correct output results. Please assist

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root/group[not(node/count='3')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <node>
          <count><xsl:value-of select="'some_results'"></xsl:value-of></count>
          <value><xsl:value-of select="'some_results'"/></value>
        </node>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node[not(count='3')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <count><xsl:value-of select="count"></xsl:value-of></count>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="value"/></value>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

If element 'node' which has child element 'count'=3 present,- map as it is.

Otherwise the output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <group>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>2</count>
      <value>value_2</value>
    </node>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>some_results</count>
      <value>some_results</value>
    </node>
    <node segment="1">
      <count>1</count>
      <value>value_1</value>
    </node>
  </group>
</root>
```

Thanks,
Darius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't it be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group[not(node/count='3')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- add missing node-->
        <node segment="1">
            <count>some_results</count>
            <value>some_results</value>
        </node>
        <!-- process existing nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```